# PlaywrightJava: Failed to create driver when adding playwright via target Plattfrom

Tags: java, osgi, playwright, playwright-java

I added Playwright via Target Plattform -> m2e PDE Integration to my Plugin Project (Is there a better way of Integration?). Playwright.create() throws the error: Failed to create driver

java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create driver

```
at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.driver.Driver.createAndInstall(Driver.java:105)

at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.driver.Driver.ensureDriverInstalled(Driver.java:57)

at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.PlaywrightImpl.createImpl(PlaywrightImpl.java:45)

at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.PlaywrightImpl.create(PlaywrightImpl.java:35)

at com.microsoft.playwright.Playwright.create(Playwright.java:110)

at com.microsoft.playwright.Playwright.create(Playwright.java:114)
```

Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: Provider "bundleresource" not installed

```
at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:212)

at java.base/java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:98)

at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.driver.jar.DriverJar.extractDriverToTempDir(DriverJar.java:128)

at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.driver.jar.DriverJar.initialize(DriverJar.java:66)

at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.driver.Driver.initialize(Driver.java:64)

at com.microsoft.playwright.impl.driver.Driver.createAndInstall(Driver.java:101)

... 9 more
```

I am aware of the workaround of setting the system Property "playwright.cli.dir" manually and build Playwright manually, but I would like to know if there is a better solution or if the playwright team is at least aware that how they handle paths and files its only working for maven projects (or at least not very robust).

Thanks for tipps and Information!